# tox+pytest gives invocation error with code -11 only on travis

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest, tox

I have code that, when I test with tox locally, passes all tests. However, on Travis, it gives the following error:

```
tests/test_cli.py::test_spin ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/travis/build/21cmfast/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/bin/py.test -vv --basetemp=/home/travis/build/21cmfast/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/tmp --cov py21cmfast (exited with code -11)
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   py36: commands failed

The command "tox" exited with 1.
```

Full output at https://travis-ci.org/21cmfast/21cmFAST/jobs/545483077

Does anyone know what code -11 means? And have any idea why it would be failing on travis but not locally?

One thing of possible note... `test_spin` is a *reasonably* intensive function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a [pytest exit code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/doc/en/usage.rst#possible-exit-codes). It's probably a [segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/segmentation-fault/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is hiding in the hardcoded path here:

```
EXTERNALTABLES = ffi.new("char[]", path.join(path.expanduser("~"), ".21CMMC").encode())
global_params.external_table_path = EXTERNALTABLES
```

The Travis environment doesn't have the path `~/.21CMMC` defined, thus reading attempts from there will fail, resulting in a segfault. If you dump the traceback on a `SIGSEGV` signal, you'll see an output similar to this one:

```
tests/test_cli.py::test_spin T_RECFAST: Unable to open file: /home/travis/.21CMMC/External_tables/recfast_LCDM.dat for reading
Aborting
Called xion_RECFAST with z=35.000000, bailing out!
Called xion_RECFAST with z=35.000000, bailing out!
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
Current thread 0x00007fba4012d700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py21cmfast/wrapper.py", line 765 in _call_c_func
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py21cmfast/wrapper.py", line 1641 in spin_temperature
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py21cmfast/cli.py", line 264 in spin
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17 in new_func
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555 in invoke
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956 in invoke
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137 in invoke
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717 in main
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/.tox/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/testing.py", line 326 in invoke
  File "/home/travis/build/21cmFAST/21cmFAST/tests/test_cli.py", line 116 in test_spin
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you dump that traceback?

Comment: Via [`faulthandler.enable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html#faulthandler.enable).

Comment: Glad I could help!